# Zookeeper leader election mechanism

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am currently reading about zookeeper. I have some doubts in Zookeeper leader election.

It has been mentioned that there are two types of leader election mechanism for Zookeeper i.e Leader Election and Fast Leader election.

Which one of the above method will be followed when we start a zookeeper server and how other followers know when a leader has went down?

Answer (score 2):

On reading more I found that, Fast Leader Election will be used for the leader election. Also, there is a configuration property electionAlgo through which we can specify the election type.

Zookeeper will use ZAB(Zookeeper Atomic Broadcast protocol) for leader election and followers will send heart beat to leader to detect leader failure. Once the heartbeat from follower to leader or leader to follower didn't reach within configured session timeout, leader election will takes place again.